# Collecting specific genome data from a file and collect it in the same title

Tags: bash

I have genomes data in a file, `genomes-seq.txt`. The titles of the sequences begin with `>`, and then the genome name:

```
>genome.1
atcg
atcg
atcggtc

>genome.2
atct
tgcgtgctt
attttt

>genome.
sdkf
sdf;ksdf
sdlfkjdslc
edsfsfv

>genome.3
as;ldkhaskjd
asdkljdsl
asdkljasdk;l

>genome.4
ekjfhdhsa
dsfkjskajd
asdknasd


>genome.1
iruuwi
sdkljbh
sdfljnsdl

>genome.234
efijhusidh
siduhygfhuji

>genome.1
ljhdcj
sdljhsdil
fweusfhygc
```

I want to collect the similar data for genome.1 in one file so it looks like this:

```
>genome.1
atcg
atcggtc

iruuwi
sdkljbh
sdfljnsdl
ljhdcj
sdljhsdil
fweusfhygc
```

But every time I do it using sed I get:

```
>genome.1
atcg
atcg
atcggtc

>genome.1
iruuwi
sdkljbh
sdfljnsdl

>genome.1
ljhdcj
sdljhsdil
fweusfhygc
```

That is, multiple `genome.1`s. How can I do it correctly so on large data set I don't need to remove all the repetitions?

Comment: Hi @paul, what is your `sed` command that you used?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Show what you tried and we can help fix your errors.

Comment: Re *"...every time I do it using `sed`..."*: You ought to include the `sed` line in the question. Otherwise, this amounts to a work order (using this site as a script-writing service).

Comment: The file format is [FASTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format).

Answer (score 3):

```
$sed -nr /\>genome.1/,/^$/p file | sed '2,${/^>genome.1$/d}'

>genome.1
atcg
atcggtc

iruuwi
sdkljbh
sdfljnsdl
ljhdcj
sdljhsdil
fweusfhygc
```

genome.1 is the key word, change depending on the list you would like to generate.

Comment: Hi Goro, can I be your `sed` friend? Where can I find such `sed` knowledge?

Comment: 1) `\>` matches end-of-word, not the literal character `>`. 2) Please use `\.` to escape the literal dot in the regular expression that is supposed to match `>genome.1`. 3) You should also anchor it at the line start and end to avoid false matches: `/^>genome\.1$/`. 4) The `-r` flag on the first sed command is not required but harmless since you don't use any characters affected by it. 5) As a rule of thumb you should escape sed commands provided through a shell to avoid easily overlooked issues.

Answer (score 0):

With perl

```
perl -00 -ne 'if (/^>genome\.1\n/) {s/// if $. > 1; print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With Awk:

```awk
{
  if (/^>/)
    in_section = 0;
  if ($0 == ">genome.1") {
    in_section = 1;
    if (!section_count++)
      print;
  } else if (in_section)
    print;
}
```

Usage:

```sh
awk '{ if (/^>/) in_section = 0; if ($0 == ">genome.1") { in_section = 1; if (!section_count++) print; } else if (in_section) print; }' genome.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if started with awk, then try this:

```
echo ">genome.1";awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"}{if($1 == "genome.1"){for(i=1;i<NF;i++){print $(i+1)}}}' file |sort -u
```

With `RS=">"` separate each running "genome" records, in each record print all fields but first, then `sort` the output list unique (parametr `-u`). If you set the `RS=">genome\."` you can write short:

```
echo -n ">genome.";awk 'BEGIN{RS=">genome."}/1/{print $0}' file |sort -ur
```